# DockerFile for dotnetcore2.0 with multiple cs project references

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-container

I am running a .netcore2.0 webapi using Visual studio 2017 for MAC. 
I have a project structure as below.

```
src
    --Solution.sln
    -- Common
        -- commonPrj
            -- Common.csproj
    --Data
        --  QM
            --  QM.csproj
        --Repo
            --Repo.csproj
    --Ser
        --  Host
            -- Api
                --api.csproj
```

I have the DOCKERFILE content as well. Which is throwing error while doing the dotnet build process as the build agent could not resolve the common.csproj/ I think my dockerfile definition is wrong. Can someone please assist in getting this work [i tried lot of option here with dockerfile]>?

```
#FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
#COPY *.csproj ./
#RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build
#COPY . ./ ./ ./
#RUN dotnet restore
#RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# build runtime image
#FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
#WORKDIR /app
#COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

#EXPOSE 5000

COPY ./out /out
WORKDIR /out
#WORKDIR /publish


ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Rando.MortgageCenter.WebAPI.dll"]
```

I am trying to build this docker image using the Docker cloud environment [cloud.docker.com/swarm]

```
Error Log from docker cloud build
Building in Docker Cloud's infrastructure...
Cloning into '.'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '104.192.143.1' to the list of known hosts.
Reset branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
KernelVersion: 4.4.0-93-generic
Arch: amd64
BuildTime: 2017-08-17T22:50:04.828747906+00:00
ApiVersion: 1.30
Version: 17.06.1-ce
MinAPIVersion: 1.12
GitCommit: 874a737
Os: linux
GoVersion: go1.8.3
Starting build of index.docker.io/systreeau/mortgagecenter:latest...
Step 1/4 : FROM microsoft/aspnetcore
---> f79840764591
Step 2/4 : COPY ./out /out
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder177013174/out: no such file or directory
ERROR: Build failed: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder177013174/out: no such file or directory
ERROR: Build failed with exit code 2
```

Comment: dockerfile is in the Api folder in the above mentioned project structure

Comment: A correction in the question ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Rando.MortgageCenter.WebAPI.dll"] -- > change it to ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "api.dll"]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So what I found was you have to place your DOCKERFILE in the src folder which is the root of the solution. so that docker context becomes this path.

Now you have a Dockerfile as below

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 as build
WORKDIR /app


COPY . . 

#COPY Solution.sln .
# RUN ls -l
RUN dotnet restore ./Solution.sln

COPY . .

RUN dotnet publish ./Ser/Host/Api/api.csproj --output /out/ --configuration Release

# runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /out .

ENTRYPOINT ["api.dll"]
```

Hope this help someone having the issue what i am facing

Comment: very common scenario when we have multiple projects.